# php OOP best practice with subclasses of a generic user class

Tags: php, class, oop

I while back I worked on a project what build a system around two different types of Users. Let's call the types Men and Woman for the simplicity of it.

We had three different classes. A User class that held the common information about all users (such as name, age and so on). This class also held a property of the type of the user man or woman). The other two classes Man and Woman extended User.

The database contained three tables. One for the User objects, one for Men objects and one for Woman objects.

The problem that I'm thinking about now is how to best create instances of a Man or Woman (based on a User-id unique for all Users). Since we wanted to create an instance of either Man or Woman depending on the user type we did it with a function that first checked the type of the user and then returned an object or either Man or Woman.

Perhaps to better explain it, it looked a little like this:

```
class User {
     private $id, $name;
     function __construct($userId) {
          // Get the information from the database and put it in instance variables
     }
}

class Man extends User {
    private $somethingManSpecific;
    function __construct($userId) {
         parent::__construct($userId);
         // Fetch info from the Man DB-table...
    }
}

class Woman extends User {
    private $somethingWomanSpecific;
    function __construct($userId) {
         parent::__construct($userId);
         // Fetch info from the Woman DB-table...
    }
}

function getUser($userId) {
    $type = find_the_type_of_user($userId); 
    if ($type == "man") return new Man($userId);
    else return new Woman($userId);
}

$fooUser = getUser(99);
```

This feels lika a weird way of doing it though and I wonder if there is a better solution for this.

Part of my question is of course how a class constructor should be seen. We used the constructor to retrieve all the attributes of the object from the database - so if you have any feedback on that it would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: The approach seems broadly valid to me; I would consider 1) putting the `getUser` function into a Factory class of some sort, and 2) moving the initialisation from the constructor to something like `protected function initialseData`, which could be marked `abstract` on the base class and avoids the need for `parent::__construct()` (the constructor would just call `$this->initialiseData()` before or after whatever generic logic was needed).

Comment: Inheritance doesn't map well onto relational databases. If you're looking for literature use those key words. Other solutions are possible. A table like: `[ user-id, username, type=[man,woman], man_property_1, man_property_2, woman_property_X, woman_property_Y ]` seems reasonable to me.

Comment: I would never use constructor to query DB (and based on it create PHP objects). That's misslieading, unclear and less that good design. Use constructore only to really create new instances (in DB and upon it in PHP). I recommend use of static getter() methods to query DB. Inside the gettter of course you must constructor, to wrap the results up, but externally it is much clearer and more acurate.